# Creating a batch file to delete a file for all users on a workstation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to delete a file for all users on a workstation.
Example: I want to delete the following: `C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\file.XX`.

I can create this to delete for any specific user, but am unsure how to create for the file to search through all user-IDs in `C:\Users\*\`.

Please note that we cannot use PowerShell, as this is disabled by our AD.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FOR /D %%f IN (C:\Users\*) DO (
  ECHO DEL %%f\AppData\Local\file.XX
)
```

Once you are sure this will act on the files you want, remove the `ECHO` and run it again to actually delete the files.

Comment: Let me recommend quotation like `DEL "%%~f\AppData\Local\file.XX"` in case there are items containing spaces. This works only if the user profile directories are at their default location, but this is the case most of the time; if not, then you needed to search the registry (using the `reg` command)...

Answer (score 1):

```
del /s "C:\users\file.xx"
```

should delete the file `file.xx` in **all** subdirectories of `c:\users`, also in `c:\users` itself.

Comment: I always forget `DEL` has this option.